# HTML Compressor | Reason for space between tags?

Tags: html

HTML Compressor leaves spaces in-between my tags. Is this necessary? Is there an option to remove them?

Comment: Possible duplicate - or answered in - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458227/removes-spaces-between-html-tags

Comment: Good point - the second answer points out that not _all_ whitespace between tags can be safely removed. I'm not familiar enough with your tool to know if the aggressive option will work with that example - I'd recommend giving it a shot. In any case, it's a good counter-example that may answer your question about the dangerousness of the aggressive option.

Comment: o.k thanks...I'll re-scan it...missed that part.

Comment: I wasn't sure how similar that was, so did not vote to close the question. It's one of those "Is it truly duplicate? Not sure..." questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary. Use the aggressive option.